# How to retain html body after sanitizing/cleaning with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am jsoup newbie. I am trying to Sanitize following HTML string. 
String html = `"<html><head><body bgcolor=\"red\"><p>sidd</p></body></html></head>"`;

I want to retain body tag so I made my white list as follows

```
    Whitelist w = Whitelist.relaxed();
    w.addTags("html");
    w.addTags("head");
    w.addTags("body");
    w.addAttributes("body","bgcolor");
```

Output of this comes as `<p>sidd</p>` . Can some one tell me how I can retain 'body' tag in my sanitized output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parse()`-method:

```
final String html = "<html><head><body bgcolor=\"red\"><p>sidd</p></body></html></head>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // Make shure you import 'org.jsoup.nodes.Document'

System.out.println(doc); // Output your html or whatever
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body bgcolor="red">
  <p>sidd</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you need only the body-tag use `doc.select("body")`. Output:

```
<body bgcolor="red">
 <p>sidd</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing using jsoup will not sanitize the html

Answer (score 0):

There's a body() method that will give you just the body:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class so {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String html = "<html><head><body bgcolor=\"red\"><p>sidd</p></body></html></head>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        System.out.println(doc.body());
    }
}
```

output:

```
<body bgcolor="red">
 <p>sidd</p>
</body>
```